# Need some help to determine the amount of recursive calls in PHP

Tags: php, recursion

I've got a, I think fairly easy question, but this is bugging me for a while now. So I figured, maybe I can get some help here.

Since recursive functions are always a bit tricky, and sometimes a bit unclear to me, I keep struggling to create a nice working solution to get my menudata.

In one of my classes I have this function, which gives me all menu-items recursively.

The thing I want is to determine at which recursion level a certain object was retrieved so I can create a nicely looking HTML output with indents for the levels of nesting.

```
public function GetObjectList($parentID = 0, $objectlist = null)
{
    if(is_null($objectlist))
    {
        $objectlist = new ObjectList("Model_Navigation");   
    }           

    $query  = MySQL::Query("SELECT * FROM `Navigation` WHERE `WebsiteID` = ".SITE_ID. " AND `LanguageID` = ".LANG_ID." AND `ParentID` = ".$parentID);

    while($result = MySQL::FetchAssoc($query))
    {           
        $object = new Model_Navigation();

        $object->ID             = $result["ID"];
        $object->WebsiteID      = $result["WebsiteID"];
        $object->LanguageID     = $result["LanguageID"];
        $object->ParentID       = $result["ParentID"];
        $object->Name           = $result["Name"];
        $object->Page           = Model_Page::GetObjectByID($result["PageID"]);
        $object->ExternalURL    = $result["ExternalURL"];
        $object->Index          = $result["Index"];
        $object->Level          = [here lies my problem];
        $objectlist->Add($object);

        self::GetObjectList($object->ID, $objectlist);
    }

    return $objectlist;
}
```

Comment: @Ben, Do u remember I told U, Sometime's Einstein also forgets the definition of Energy as u have in this case of "post-increment", Should I call ur doubt as Homework??? No, never.. Because every body mises something, sometimes..... God Bless

Comment: Haha yeah, i've your comment on my comment in your post ;) I guess you;re right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public function GetObjectList($parentID = 0, $objectlist = null, $level = 1)
{
    if(is_null($objectlist))
    {
        $objectlist = new ObjectList("Model_Navigation");   
    }           

    $query  = MySQL::Query("SELECT * FROM `Navigation` WHERE `WebsiteID` = ".SITE_ID. " AND `LanguageID` = ".LANG_ID." AND `ParentID` = ".$parentID);

    while($result = MySQL::FetchAssoc($query))
    {           
        $object = new Model_Navigation();

        $object->ID             = $result["ID"];
        $object->WebsiteID      = $result["WebsiteID"];
        $object->LanguageID     = $result["LanguageID"];
        $object->ParentID       = $result["ParentID"];
        $object->Name           = $result["Name"];
        $object->Page           = Model_Page::GetObjectByID($result["PageID"]);
        $object->ExternalURL    = $result["ExternalURL"];
        $object->Index          = $result["Index"];
        $object->Level          = $level;
        $objectlist->Add($object);

        self::GetObjectList($object->ID, $objectlist, $level+1);
    }

    return $objectlist;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! By I'm a bit confused now... Why does $level+1 work and $level++ doesn't? While it does, in my opinion, the same...?

Comment: @Ben Fransen: `$level++` is 'post-increment', so the value returned by the expression is before the increment. `++$level` would work. see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

Comment: Thanks for explaining Tom! Now you mention it becomes clear, +1

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add a parameter to the function call that stores the number of calls. At the first call just make that 0, increment the value inside the function and use it in the recursive call.

Comment: I've tried that, but the levelcount doesn't match when I do that.